# SharePoint Hosted App : Workflows require a WSP package to be included in the project

Tags: sharepoint, hosted-app

I am having an issue when packaging up a SharePoint Hosted app. I have a SP Hosted app Project and another project within the same solution that creates a WSP file when packaged. Now, whenever I try to package the app so it generates the .app file. An error comes up with this msg : ***Workflows require a WSP package to be included in the project. Adding a module to the project will create a WSP.***

I have tried to good the error but no luck.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Try removing workflow project temporarily from solution. Once your app is packaged, add it back.  Ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ba7zx39(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Tried that, didnt work. Thank you for help